# Can GCC output code of older version?

Tags: gcc

Can I use GCC 4.8 to provide the compilation features that were available in an older version say GCC 4.1? I have used Java and seen that we can use use JDK7 to output JDK6 compatible code, was wondering if something similar was available in GCC.

Comment: What specific features are you looking for?

Comment: Nothing specific, had a code base from a project I wrote a 3-4 years back. Complied it today with GCC4.8 and found lots of errors/failing tests. Was wondering if such a feature was available, or I need to install an old compiler.

Comment: Very, very little has ever been removed from GCC's language features in later versions. I don't think that's the source of your issues.

Comment: Agreed that very little has been removed, however optimizations have changes, like strict aliasing etc, which plays havoc with the old behavior.

Comment: The answer is no, but there should be enough options that you don't need that.